# Error with bootstrap-sass. Migrating to rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I trying to migrate from rails 3.2 to rails 4.0.1 and when I do all by this guide http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

I have error with bootstrapp css

```
    File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
Load paths:
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/app/assets/images
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/vendor/assets/images
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/arseniy/Work/requests/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/fonts
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /home/arseniy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@requests/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.0.2.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  (in /home/arseniy/Work/requests/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss:3)
```

This my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
.footer {
  text-align: right;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as explained in [this migration Guide](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide) Bootstrap now applies the "Mobile First" Practice.
Therefore you don't need responsive css anymore, and all necessary code is included in the "bootstrap.css" file.
Just remove your

```
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Line and it should be fine!